# Barrier in bash, can it be done easily?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a bash script that executes three scripts in parallel

```
./script1 &
./script2 &
./script3 &
```

Now, let us say that ./script4 depends on script1, script2 and script3. How can I force it to wait for those, while still executing the three scripts in parallel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`wait`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28command%29) a built-in command available in [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-wait) and in some other shells.
<sup>(see equivalent command [WAITFOR](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) on Windows)</sup>

#### [`wait` documentation](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html)

> Wait for each specified process to complete and return its termination
>   status.
>
> ```
> Syntax
>       wait [n ...]
> Key
>    n   A process ID or a job specification
> ```
>
> Each `n` can be a process ID or a job specification; if a job
>   specification is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are
>   waited for.
>
> If `n` is not given, all currently active child processes are waited
>   for, and the return status is zero.
>
> If `n` specifies a non-existent process or job, the return status is
>   `127`. Otherwise, the return status is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.

#### Simple solution

Below `wait` waits indefinitely for all currently active child processes to be all ended (i.e. in this case the three scripts).

```
./script1 &
./script2 &
./script3 &
wait       # waits for all child processes
./script4
```

#### Store the PIDs in shell local variables

```
./script1 & pid1=$!
./script2 & pid2=$!
./script3 & pid3=$!
wait $pid1 $pid2 $pid3  # waits for 3 PIDs
./script4
```

#### Store the PIDs in temporary files

```
./script1 & echo $! >1.pid
./script2 & echo $! >2.pid
./script3 & echo $! >3.pid
wait $(<1.pid) $(<2.pid) $(<3.pid)
rm 1.pid 2.pid 3.pid            # clean up
./script4
```

This last solution pollutes the current directory with three files (`1.pid`, `2.pid` and `3.pid`). One of these file may be corrupted before `wait` call. Moreover these files could be left in the file-system in case of crash.

Answer (score 6):

From the `bash` man page:

```
wait [n ...]
    Wait for each specified process and return its termination status.
    Each `n` may be a process ID or a job specification.... If `n` is not
    given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return
    status is zero.
```

---

The easiest implementation might be for your last script to start the others.  That way it's easy for it to store their PIDs and pass them to `wait`.

Comment: +1.  Nothing like doing a basic check in the documentation to answer questions....

Comment: @CarlNorum: True, but sometimes you need to know what you're looking for before you can find it!  Even experienced programmers need a pointer to the right docs every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

I whipped up something quickly years ago, but now I wanted nested parallelism. This is what I came up with:

```
# Run each supplied argument as a bash command, inheriting calling environment.
# bash_parallel's can be nested, though escaping quotes can be tricky -- define helper function for such cases.
# Example: bash_parallel "sleep 10" "ls -altrc"
function bash_parallel
{
    (   
        i=0
        unset BASH_PARALLEL_PIDS # Do not inherit BASH_PARALLEL_PIDS from parent bash_parallel (if any)

        for cmd in "$@"
        do
            ($cmd) &             # In subshell, so sibling bash_parallel's wont interfere
            BASH_PARALLEL_PIDS[$i]=$!
            echo "bash_parallel started PID ${BASH_PARALLEL_PIDS[$i]}: $cmd"
            i=$(($i + 1))
        done

        echo "bash_parallel waiting for PIDs: ${BASH_PARALLEL_PIDS[@]}"
        wait ${BASH_PARALLEL_PIDS[@]}
    ) # In subshell, so ctrl-c will kill still-running children. 
}
```

Use:

```
eisbaw@leno:~$ time (bash_parallel "sleep 10" "sleep 5")
bash_parallel started PID 30183: sleep 10
bash_parallel started PID 30184: sleep 5
bash_parallel waiting for PIDs: 30183 30184

real    0m10.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
```