# Run multiple commands in parallel, and return whenever one of them fails or all of them succeed

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I've seen the following question : [Bash run two commands and get output from both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572295/bash-run-two-commands-and-get-output-from-both) which almost responds to my need.

However, the wait command is blocking, so that means that if command 2 fails before command 1 succeeds, the command will not return when command 2 fails but only when command 1 succeeds.

Is it possible to run multiple commands in parallel, and return 1 whenever one of them fails and return 0 if all of them succeed  (And returning as soon as possible) ?

It would be even better if that is possible using standard commands (like xargs or parallel), but also ok if it is written using bash.

Comment: If one of the command fails, do you want to kill the other before returning or keep the other running?

Comment: Yes, that would be better (killing the other command)

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145528/barrier-in-bash-can-it-be-done-easily) ? It simulates the behaviour of a barier in bash

Comment: @Ploutox That's a good start but it crucially lacks the facility to exit early if one of the subprocesses fails. (And, it's trivial.)

Comment: @tripleee how would you implement it ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/687994/258523) answer has some code that might be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

This code gives the right exit code, and kills the survivor process:

```
#/bin/bash

# trap for SIGTERM and set RET_VALUE to false
trap "RET_VAL=false" SIGTERM

MY_PID=$$
# Initialize RET_VALUE to true
RET_VAL=true

# This function will executed be in a separate job (see below)
thread_listener() {
    # Starts the long time job 
    ./longJob.sh &
    PID=$!
    # trap for sigterm and kill the long time process
    trap "kill $PID" SIGTERM
    echo waiting for $PID
    echo Parent $MY_PID
    # Send a SIGTERM to parent job in case of failure
    wait $PID || kill $MY_PID
    exit
}

echo $MY_PID

# Runs thread listener in a separate job
thread_listener &
PID1=$!

# Runs thread listener in a separate job
thread_listener &
PID2=$!

wait
# send sigterm to PID1 and PID2 if present
kill $PID1 2> /dev/null
kill $PID2 2> /dev/null
# returns RET_VALUE
$RET_VAL
```

See the comments for an explanation of the code.
The trick is to starts jobs able to accept or send signal to parent job if needed.

The child job send a signal to the parent in case of a failure of its long time job and the parent send a signal to its childs after the wait (it the parent receive a signal the wait returns immediatly)

Answer (score 0):

The recent versions of GNU Parallel have focused on exactly that problem. Kill running children, if a single one fails:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 'echo {};{}' ::: true false true true false
```

Kill running children, if a single one succeeds:

```
parallel --halt now,success=1 'echo {};{}' ::: true false true true false
```

Kill running children, if 20% fails:

```
parallel -j1 --halt now,fail=20% 'echo {#} {};{}' ::: true true true false true true false true false true
```

Kill the child with signals TERM,TERM,TERM,KILL while waiting 50 ms between each signal:

```
parallel --termseq TERM,50,TERM,50,TERM,50,KILL -u --halt now,fail=1 'trap "echo TERM" SIGTERM; sleep 1;echo {};{}' ::: true false true true false
```

Comment: How can you use commands longer than one word ? for example `parallel --halt now,fail=1 'echo {};{}' ::: true "echo 'hi'"` fails with `/bin/bash: echo 'hi': command not found`

Comment: It works if I use : `parallel --halt now,fail=1 "echo {}; eval {}" ::: "echo 'ho'" "echo 'hi'"`

Comment: Yup. Either use eval or only use {}: `parallel --halt now,fail=1 {} ::: "echo 'ho'" "echo 'hi'"` Typically it will be used as: `cat file | parallel --halt now,fail=1`

Answer (score 0):

Solved a similar situation, share here if ever it helps to someone.

I have got three commands to run.

- `server1` and `server2` are long running commands, e.g. webservers.
- `healthcheck` command runs some checks to make sure that the servers are okay. It requires the two servers up to perform the tests.

Required behavior:

- If `healthcheck` is successful (return code is 0), block until the servers are running. This is normal operation.
- If `healthcheck` fails, return immediately. This is wanted if there is a problem with servers.

The following does the job for me:

```sh
server1 & server2 & healthcheck && wait
```